# getting error while sending querystring in on click javascript in hyperlink in .net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

i have a hyperlink which should open a new window with querystring values. getting error saying . there is error in onclick property
**server tag is not well formed**

```
<asp:HyperLink Target="_blank" ID="Refname" 
  Text='<%#Eval("RefCount") %>' runat="server" 
  NavigateUrl=#  
  onClick='<%# "window.open('AssignedRequestsNew.aspx" + 
          "?RefId=" + 
          Server.UrlEncode(Eval("RefID").ToString())','name','height=550, 
            width=790,toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,
            scrollbars=yes,resizable=no'); return false;%>'  />
```

i used this

```
     <a id="HyperLink2" 
     runat="server" 
     NavigateUrl='#'  
     onclick="window.open('AssignedRequestsNew.aspx?RefId=','name','height=550, width=790,toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no, menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no'); return false;" 
     Target="_blank">
<%#Eval("RefCount") %>
</a>
```

compiling and opening new window, but unable to pass values through query string, can u help me to pass query string values

Comment: Is it the Navigate URL? shouldn't it be '#' ?

Comment: ok, but thats not give error in compile time. i will change it to #. i think it should be # only @bloC

Answer (score 0):

Write a JavaScript function and call it on `onclick` like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlDemo" runat="server" onclick="openNewWindows()"
     style="cursor:pointer; text-decoration:underline;">HyperLink Demo
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

The onClick function's quotes are messed up. This should work

```
   <asp:HyperLink Target="_blank" ID="Refname" Text='<%#Eval("RefCount") %>' runat="server" NavigateUrl = '#'  onClick='<%# "window.open('AssignedRequestsNew.aspx?RefId="& Server.UrlEncode(Eval('RefID').ToString()) & "  ', name , height=550, width=790,toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no'); return false; ')" %>'  />
```

Comment: still im getting error of sever tag is not well formed@hari hara chandan

Comment: You should have a closer look at this and make sure the quotes are opened and closed properly, that's where your issue is.

Comment: yes i know . i did something wrong in quotes in onclick function@hari hara chandan

Comment: I have made an edit, try & instead of + when adding strings

Answer (score 0):

Your `onClick` value is indeed malformed.  You have an inconsistent mix of single and double quotes.